# Let $p_1,p_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ be distinct prime numbers. Show that $|\cdot|_{p_1}\not\sim|\cdot|_{p_2}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $p_1,p_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ be distinct prime numbers. Show that $|\cdot|_{p_1}\not\sim|\cdot|_{p_2}$ by finding a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that is Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot|_{p_1}$ but not Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot|_{p_2}$.

I am having trouble finding such a Cauchy sequence. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Start by finding the simplest non-constant sequence that converges to $0$ in $| \cdot |_{p_1}$.

Comment: What of $p_1^n$?